# Sping Boot to generate jar with only class files and place dependency in a separate location

Tags: spring-boot

I would like to create jar's with only class files for my project and to copy all it's dependency into a separate folder and put these in docker.

Comment: better add more description on in what folder structure you want to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy all dependency into a separate folder using maven's [copy-dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html)

Using maven configuration profile and exec tag's you can create jar's only with class files.

Use maven [manifest](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/manifest-customization.html) tag in your pom.xml, So that you can add entries in your manifest files to locate where is the jar placed. So that when application boot's the jar will take dependency from that location.

While creating docker files, make sure to copy all the dependencies. You can use docker volumes